# Audio not working in APK

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova, audio

I've made a app in HTML5 CSS and jQuery on Phonegap but the audio is not working when it is an .APK file. I tested my app on the Phonegap developer app and on that, the app is working great! But when it is an .APK file the audio is not working anymore.. Is there something wrong in my config.xml?

http://pastebin.com/edVTUghw

Btw, this is how I play audio in my game.js:

```
pop = new Audio('/android_asset/www/sounds/bubble-pop.wav')
music = new Audio('/android_asset/www/sounds/music.mp3')
fail = new Audio('/android_asset/www/sounds/fail.wav')

pop.play();
music.play();
fail.play();
```

EDIT:
I want to try the Media Plugin of Cordova but don't know how to use it in my project. Does someone know how to? I really want to play sounds in my app.

Comment: maybe the phonegap developer app uses a plugin for audio, check the phonegap developer app source code

Comment: do you have use media phonegap plugin on your project?

Comment: @prabhu No. Is using a plugin required to play sounds?

Comment: yes. If you played any audio file on your app you will should use media plugin on your phonegap build. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_media_media.md.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you building phonegap app locally! Assuming yes, you can install media plugin using CLI

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media
```

This command will install media plugin. Then after device ready function is triggered,you can use this code

```
src='sounds/music.mp3';
my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
my_media.play();

function onSuccess() {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
    }

    // onError Callback
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }
```

Here is a complete example & documentation

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I am gonna try this tonight. I will keep you guys up-to-date!